# How to restrict acces to Solana programs only to owners of certain NFT collection using Sol Cerberus

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

I am using [Sol Cerberus](https://solcerberus.com/) to manage the access to my Solana program, but I don't know how can I call my instruction in javascript to test the access using an NFT collection.

For instance this is my Solana program:

```rust
use sol_cerberus_macros::rule;

declare_id!("MY_PROGRAM_ID");

#[program]
pub mod sol_cerberus_demo {

    use super::*;

    #[rule(Stats, View)]
    pub fn view_stats(ctx: Context<Add>) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::view::view(ctx)
    }

}
```

How can I execute `view_stats` in my web3 application using an NFT to authenticate the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [good example in the docs](https://docs.solcerberus.com/docs/get-started/test-access/#testing-nft-acccess). For instance if you have created the role `"Authorized"` and assigned it to your NFT collection address `"MY_NFT_COLLECTION_MINT_ADDRESS"` in the [SC Manager](https://solcerberus.com/app), then you can do something like this:

```js
{PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js';

const solCerberus = new SolCerberus(connection, myWallet, {appId: new PublicKey("PASTE_YOUR_SC_APP_ID_HERE")});
await solCerberus.fetchAllRoles()
await solCerberus.fetchPerms()

await solCerberus.login({
  nfts: [
    [
      new PublicKey("MY_NFT_MINT_ADDRESS"), 
      new PublicKey("MY_NFT_COLLECTION_MINT_ADDRESS")
    ]
  ]
})

if (solCerberus.hasPerm("Stats", "View")){
    try {
        await yourAnchorProgram.methods
            .viewStats()
            .accounts({
            ...(await solCerberus.accounts("Stats", "View")), // Fetches the requires SC accounts
            })
            .rpc();
    } catch (e) {
        // If user is not authorized, you can easily catch the error and inform the user:
        if (solCerberus.isUnauthorizedError(e)) {
            alert("Not authorized!")
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't know in advance NFT addresses, you can easily fetch them following [Solana's cookbook example](https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-all-nfts-from-a-wallet).